# $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript won't work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm trying to get the responde body of a window opened by cordovaInAppBrowser... this is my code:

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(LOGIN_PAGE_URL,'_blank',options);//               

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event)
    {
       if(event.url.indexOf(LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL)>-1) 
       {
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){ 

                alert("loadstop")

                $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript(
                { code: "document.body.innerHTML" },
                function(data)
                {
                    alert("Code Inserted Succesfully");

                }
                );


            });
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
```

I don't know why but the alert("loadstop") is fired, but the alert("Code Inserted Successfully") not!

If i do

```
 $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript(
            { code: "alert(document.body.innerHTML)" },
```

it alerts the body content correctly...
I'm going crazy!
Please help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I solve it.
`$cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript` is promise and you should put callback to `.then()` like:

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript( { 
  code: "document.body.innerHTML" 
}).then(function(data) {
  alert("Code Inserted Succesfully");
});
```